# How to define Quaggajs in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new using the library quaggajs and it is difficult to find information. I am implementing this library in my project and I am not sure if I am performing the steps correctly. I have added the quagga.js file in the Scripts folder and I have added this to my view and I am having this error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: Quagga is not defined
at Object.init (114:13)
at 224:15**

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Barcode";
}
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div id="interactive" class="viewport"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <div id="result_strip">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var AppQuagga = {
        init: function () {
            var self = this;

            Quagga.init(this.state, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    return self.handleError(err);
                }
                //Quagga.registerResultCollector(resultCollector);
                Quagga.start();

                Quagga.onProcessed(function (result) {
                    var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
                        drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

                    if (result) {
                        if (result.boxes) {
                            drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
                            result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
                                return box !== result.box;
                            }).forEach(function (box) {
                                Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: "green", lineWidth: 2 });
                            });
                        }

                        if (result.box) {
                            Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, { x: 0, y: 1 }, drawingCtx, { color: "#00F", lineWidth: 2 });
                        }

                        if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
                            Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, { x: 'x', y: 'y' }, drawingCtx, { color: 'red', lineWidth: 3 });
                        }
                    }
                });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
                    var capabilities = {};
                    if (typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function') {
                        try {
                            capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
                            track.applyConstraints({ advanced: [{ zoom: 2.5 }] });
                        } catch (e) { }
                    }
                }, 500);
            });
        },
        handleError: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        state: {
            inputStream: {
                type: "LiveStream",
                constraints: {
                    facingMode: "user"
                }
            },
            locator: {
                patchSize: "medium",
                halfSample: true
            },
            numOfWorkers: (navigator.hardwareConcurrency ? navigator.hardwareConcurrency : 4),
            frequency: 20,
            decoder: {
                readers: [{
                    format: "code_128_reader",
                    config: {}
                }, {
                    format: "ean_reader",
                    config: {
                    }
                }, {
                    format: "code_39_reader",
                    config: {}
                    },
                    {
                        format: "codabar_reader",
                        config: {}
                    },
                    //{
                    //    format: "code_39_vin_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //},
                    //{
                    //    format: "ean_8_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //},{
                    //    format: "upc_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //}, {

                    //    format: "upc_e_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //}, {

                    //    format: "i2of5_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //}, {
                    //    format: "2of5_reader",
                    //    config: {}
                    //}, 
                    {
                    format: "code_93_reader",
                    config: {}

                }]
            },
            locate: true
        },
        lastResult: null
    };



    AppQuagga.init();

    Quagga.onDetected(function (result) {
        var code = result.codeResult.code;

        if (code != null) {
            if (AppQuagga.lastResult !== code) {
                AppQuagga.lastResult = code;

                var $node = null;
                $node = $('<p>Read: ' + code + '</p>');
                $("#result_strip").prepend($node);
               // window.location.href = '@Url.Action("SerialNumber", "Equipment")' + 'CVHFPD2';

            }
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        var track = Quagga.CameraAccess.getActiveTrack();
        var capabilities = {};
        if (typeof track.getCapabilities === 'function') {
            try {
                capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
                track.applyConstraints({ advanced: [{ zoom: 2.5 }] });
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    }, 500);
</script>
<style>
    #interactive.viewport {
        position: relative;
    }

        #interactive.viewport > canvas, #interactive.viewport > video {
            max-width: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }

    canvas.drawing, canvas.drawingBuffer {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }



    .reader-config-group label > span {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .reader-config-group label > select, .reader-config-group label > input {
        max-width: calc(50% - 2px);
    }

    #interactive.viewport {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It is not enough to just add the `quagga.js` file to the `Scripts` folder -- you also need to make sure that it gets loaded on the client-side.  You have client-side javascript that expects quagga to be loaded but it is not loaded, therefore the error.  Try adding this near the top of your view: `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/quagga.js")`

Comment: ok great if I add <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/quagga/0.11.6/quagga.min.js"></script>
can work too?

Comment: Yes, that should work.